# What is the difference between Doosra and Teesra?

Tags: cricket, terminology

What is the basic difference between Doosra and Teesra? I know off-spinner bowls the other one which is called Doosra but what is Teesra and how is it different to Doosra?

Comment: Well Said! Pehla Doosra Teesra, One Two Three :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doosra and teesra, both these bowling techniques were invented to deceive the batsman.

Doosra and teesra both are Urdu words which means "the second one" and "the third one" respectively.

Doosra is the technique use by an off spin bowler and it results in leg spin, but the bowling action remains as off-spin (for left-arm bowlers the case is in reverse).

Teesra looks like the ball will turns a lot in off or leg but it results in less turn. The batsman can't judge the ball to where it would turn.

Both these techniques were invented by Saqlain Mushtaq.

Doosra is used well by most of the current off-break bowlers but, teesra is being used successfully by Saeed Ajmal.

Comment: Could you explain the Teesra a bit more clearly?
I'm still confused. 

Doosra is like the off-spinner's analogue of the Googly.
Teesra?

Comment: @Yaitzme, if you watched the asia cup match between Pakistan and Bangladesh, they showed Ajmal's variation between Doosra and Teesra. See this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gVQ6PtzX6w) about Ajmal's variation in a test match.

Comment: [This is an interesting read](http://www.espncricinfo.com/page2/content/story/549102.html) - Saeed Ajmal says he doesn't really have a teesra.

Answer (score 2):

Tesra is actually a cross seaming or scrambled seam delivery. But doosra is a delivery which is built on clockwise and anticlockwise movements. It turns from leg to off stump (for a right-handed batsman).

It can be delivered by two methods:

1. wrist and back of the hand towards the batsman.
2. flicking the ball anticlockwise from the middle and second finger.

Answer (score 1):

Teesra is basically a backspin bowl in which the ball is released in such a way that it spins towards the bowler so due to magnus effect, ball will be in the air flat and after pitching it will either skid or gets slow...hence the batsman will not be able to time the ball correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Doosra is analogous to googly except it turns more than googly and is very difficult to bowl without chucking wheares teesra is simply a backspiner with very small side turn it is analogus to a leg spinner's Slider When bowling a teesra the bowler keeps the exact grip as the off spin but instead of imparting spin to the ball he simply let go the ball rolling over his fingers just like a seamer does while swinging the ball so the ball skids and reaches the batsman late which can decieve him while facing a quick off spinner

Answer (score -1):

So far this delivery has been used for well over a hundred years. But the delivery has recently been re-invented by Saqlain Mushtaq and he occasionally used it. He has stated that the teesra is still a work in progress and that he wants to hone the delivery so that the batsman become even more confused about where the ball is going to spin and whether it will spin at all. Saeed Ajmal claimed to have learned this art and has used it occasionally in the 2011 World Cup and after that